# iPhone 3G does not see transferred songs

Tags: sync, iphone, media

Please help! Ive transferred a few songs to my iPhone 3G 8GB phone using a variety of apps. Rhythmbox and also gtkpod. Both transfer the songs to my cell just fine, but when I try to view them on the phone... they don't show. They must be there, because if I plug the phone into another computer I can see the songs and transfer them to the computer using Rhythmbox.

My drive time to work just went from 15 minutes one way to an hour and half and talk radio is killing me :) Id really appreciate any tips I could do to get my songs showing on the phone. I have the iPhone software update 5.0 so its fairly new.

I have done a few tips from other questions like installing libimobiledevice, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried using Banshee to transfer your music?

Comment: I forgot to include that Im running Ubuntu 11.10 - 64bit on both computers I have. Unfortunately, Banshee crashes on both of my systems. I have a laptop and a desktop.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to your home folder.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files.
3. Navigate to `.gconf/apps/banshee/state/ipod`.
4. Delete the `%gconf.xml` file (it will be recreated the next time you start Rhythmbox).
5. Restart Rhythmbox. If it isn't plugged in already, plug in your iPhone.

Now you should be able to view your music files on your iPhone.